# Get key by more than one value in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, get, key

Maybe the `dict` is not intended to be used in this way, but I need to add more than one value to the same key. My intension is to use a kind of transitory property. If my dict is `A:B` and `B:C`, than I want to have the dict `A:[B,C]`.

Let's make an example in order to explain better what I'd like to do:

```
numDict={'60':['4869'], '4869':['629'], '13':['2']}
```

I want it to return:

```
{'60':['4869','629'], '13':['2']}
```

For just two elements, it is possible to use something like this:

```
result={}
for key in numDict.keys():
    if [key] in numDict.values():
        result[list(numDict.keys())[list(numDict.values()).index([key])]]=[key]+numDict[key]
```

---

But what about if I have more elements? For example:

```
numDict={'60':['4869'], '4869':['629'], '13':['2'], '629':['427'}
```

What can I do in order to get returned `{'60':[4869,629,427'], '13':['2']}`?

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? what have you tried?

Comment: I don't really think this is going to be easy. Dictionaries have no order in python, so it isn't possible to know whether a key is at the top of the chain or not.

Comment: It sounds like you want transitive closure, except that you also want to remove "intermediate" entries afterwards.  How would you want to handle cyclic references, e.g. `{1:[2], 2:[1]}`?  Or are you certain that cycles cannot occur?

Comment: MaorVeitsman the problem is that with more than two elements it just doesn't work that code, and I don't know how to proceed.

cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yes, I know, but what type would be better?

TomKarzes I'm quite sure there will not be those cyclic references.

Comment: Look up "transitive closure", and follow it with a post-pass to remove every node that has a predecessor (but note that you will remove cycles in the process).

Comment: As @coldspeed said, Dictionaries have no order so i think you can try List instead. Ex: numDict=[['60', '4869'], ['4869', '629'], ['13', '2']] may be it easier to make [['60', [4869,629,427], [13, '2']]

Comment: I think a recursive function might be useful here too - just be careful you don't get an infinite loop

Comment: @You'reawesome maybe it is possible, I can simply convert that list  [['60', [4869,629,427], [13, '2']] in the dict {'60':[4869,629,427'], '13':['2']}, can't I?

Comment: @chasmani the loop is the problem, I don't know what condition to insert

Comment: Sounds like your data would be better organized in a tree data structure. [Searching](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+tree&ia=qa) reveals a few different implementations in Python. Once your data is in a tree, it is then trivial to start from a parent and get all descendants in order.

Comment: @You'reawesome moreover, I was thinking about another problem: to work on lists, I can't use something like dict.values() or dict.keys(), so it would be a lot of cycles, am I right?

Comment: @Luca yes, but you can loop all the list to get keys and values

Answer (score 0):

I have written a code for it. See if it helps.

What I have done is to go on **diving in** till i can go (hope you understand this statement) and mark them as *visited* as they will no longer be required. At the end I filter out the *root* keys.

```
numDict={'60':['4869'], '4869':['629'], '13':['2'], '629':['427']}

l = list(numDict) # list of keys
l1 = {i:-1 for i in numDict} # to track visited keys (initialized to -1 initially)

for i in numDict:
    # if key is root and diving in is possible
    if l1[i] == -1 and numDict[i][0] in l:
        t = numDict[i][0]
        while(t in l): # dive deeper and deeper
            numDict[i].extend(numDict[t]) # update the value of key
            l1[t] = 1 # mark as visited
            t = numDict[t][0]
# filter the root keys
answer = {i:numDict[i] for i in numDict if l1[i] == -1}
print(answer)
```

Output:

```
{'60': ['4869', '629', '427'], '13': ['2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def unchain(d):
    #assemble a collection of keys that are not also values. These will be the keys of the final dict. 
    top_level_keys = set(d.keys()) - set(d.values())

    result = {}
    for k in top_level_keys:
        chain = []
        #follow the reference chain as far as necessary.
        value = d[k]
        while True:
            if value in chain: raise Exception("Referential loop detected: {} encountered twice".format(value))
            chain.append(value)
            if value not in d: break
            value = d[value]           
        result[k] = chain
    return result

numDict={'60':'4869', '4869':'629', '13':'2', '629':'427'}
print(unchain(numDict))
```

Result:

```
{'60': ['4869', '629', '427'], '13': ['2']}
```

You might notice that I changed the layout of `numDict` since it's easier to process if the values aren't one-element lists. But if you're dead set on keeping it that way, you can just add `d = {k:v[0] for k,v in d.items()}` to the top of `unchain`, to convert from one to the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own structure, consisting of a reverse mapping of `(values, key)`, and a dictionary of `(key, [values])`. Adding a `key, value` pair consists of following a chain of existing entries via the reverse mapping, until it finds the correct location; in case it does not exist, it introduces a new key entry:

```
class Groupir:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mapping = {}
        self.reverse_mapping = {}

    def add_key_value(self, k, v):
        self.reverse_mapping[v] = k
        val = v
        key = k
        while True:
            try:
                self.reverse_mapping[val]
                key = val
                val = self.reverse_mapping[val]
            except KeyError:
                try:
                    self.mapping[val].append(v)
                except KeyError:
                    self.mapping[val] = [v]
                break
```

with this test client:

```
groupir = Groupir()
groupir.add_key_value(60, 4869)
print(groupir.mapping)
groupir.add_key_value(4869, 629)
print(groupir.mapping)
groupir.add_key_value(13, 2)
print(groupir.mapping)
groupir.add_key_value(629, 427)
print(groupir.mapping)
```

#### outputs:

```
{60: [4869]}
{60: [4869, 629]}
{60: [4869, 629], 13: [2]}
{60: [4869, 629, 427], 13: [2]}
```

#### Restrictions:

Cycles as mentioned in comments.
Non unique keys
Non unique values
Probably some corner cases to take care of.